# DTW memory usage in Java

Tags: java, jsp, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have found the `Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)` library which coded in `Java`. Floating point array (`float []`) as an input and pass by `JSP`.

However, I have triple confirmed that the huge memory usage problem is caused by the `DTW library`.

Java always prompt me that `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"`. Besides, DTW algorithm always use around 2-3 GB for performing DTW.

I think the root cause that is caused by global variable, am I correct?

Would you please help me to improve and keep the program with low memory usage?

JSP Code:

```
...
float[] integer_hum_UDS = new float[hum_uds.length];
float[] integer_midi_UDS = new float[midi_uds.length];
...
DTW dtw = new DTW(integer_midi_UDS, integer_hum_UDS);  //<- Huge Memory usage statement
float distance = dtw.getDistance();
```

Java Code:

```
public class DTW {

    protected float[] seq1;
    protected float[] seq2;
    protected int[][] warpingPath;

    protected int n;
    protected int m;
    protected int K;

    protected float warpingDistance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param query     
     * @param templete  
     */
    public DTW(float[] sample, float[] templete) {
        seq1 = sample;
        seq2 = templete;

        n = seq1.length;    
        m = seq2.length;
        K = 1;

        warpingPath = new int[n + m][2];    // max(n, m) <= K < n + m
        warpingDistance = 0;

        this.compute();
    }

        public void clear() {
            seq1 = null;
            seq2 = null;
            warpingPath = null;
            n = 0;
            m = 0;
            K = 0;
            warpingDistance = 0;

            System.gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        }


    public void compute() {
        float accumulatedDistance = 0;

        float[][] d = new float[n][m];  // local distances
        float[][] D = new float[n][m];  // global distances

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                d[i][j] = distanceBetween(seq1[i], seq2[j]);
            }
        }

        D[0][0] = d[0][0];

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            D[i][0] = d[i][0] + D[i - 1][0];
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
            D[0][j] = d[0][j] + D[0][j - 1];
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
                accumulatedDistance = Math.min(Math.min(D[i-1][j], D[i-1][j-1]), D[i][j-1]);
                accumulatedDistance += d[i][j];
                D[i][j] = accumulatedDistance;
            }
        }
        accumulatedDistance = D[n - 1][m - 1];

        int i = n - 1;
        int j = m - 1;
        int minIndex = 1;

        warpingPath[K - 1][0] = i;
        warpingPath[K - 1][1] = j;

        while ((i + j) != 0) {
            if (i == 0) {
                j -= 1;
            } else if (j == 0) {
                i -= 1;
            } else {    // i != 0 && j != 0
                float[] array = { D[i - 1][j], D[i][j - 1], D[i - 1][j - 1] };
                minIndex = this.getIndexOfMinimum(array);

                if (minIndex == 0) {
                    i -= 1;
                } else if (minIndex == 1) {
                    j -= 1;
                } else if (minIndex == 2) {
                    i -= 1;
                    j -= 1;
                }
            } // end else
            K++;
            warpingPath[K - 1][0] = i;
            warpingPath[K - 1][1] = j;
        } // end while
        warpingDistance = accumulatedDistance / K;

        //this.reversePath(warpingPath);

                //Clear
                this.clear();
                //d = null;
                //D = null;
                //warpingPath = null;
                //accumulatedDistance = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the order of the warping path (increasing order)
     * 
     * @param path  the warping path in reverse order
     */

        /*
    protected void reversePath(int[][] path) {
        int[][] newPath = new int[K][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                newPath[i][j] = path[K - i - 1][j];
            }
        }
        warpingPath = newPath;
    }
        */

    /**
     * Returns the warping distance
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public float getDistance() {
        return warpingDistance;
    }

    /**
     * Computes a distance between two points
     * 
     * @param p1    the point 1
     * @param p2    the point 2
     * @return      the distance between two points
     */
    protected float distanceBetween(float p1, float p2) {
        return (p1 - p2) * (p1 - p2);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the index of the minimum element from the given array
     * 
     * @param array     the array containing numeric values
     * @return              the min value among elements
     */
    protected int getIndexOfMinimum(float[] array) {
        int index = 0;
        float val = array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < val) {
                val = array[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns a string that displays the warping distance and path
     */
    public String toString() {
        String retVal = "Warping Distance: " + warpingDistance + "\n";
                /*
        retVal += "Warping Path: {";
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            retVal += "(" + warpingPath[i][0] + ", " +warpingPath[i][1] + ")";
            retVal += (i == K - 1) ? "}" : ", ";

        }
                */
        return retVal;
    }

    /**
     * Tests this class
     * 
     * @param args  ignored
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] n2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 19, 49.7555f};
        float[] n1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        DTW dtw = new DTW(n1, n2);
        System.out.println(dtw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to review working code?

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your suggestion.